# How to allow all characters in a url in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to accept an apostrophe as a valid character in a Django URL. In fact, I think I would be ok accepting all characters in a url. How do I do this in Django?

The url code I have looks like this:

```
url(r'^view/(?P<category>[\w\s-]+)$', views.view, name='view'),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work

```
url(r'^view/(?P<category>.+)$', views.view, name='view'),
```

`.` is a regex metachar that matches anything save for newline.